# Source of alleged San Ignacio of Lyola quote: ‘In a besieged city, all dissent is treason.’

Tags: quote-source, religion, politics

I'm trying to find the source of the quote in the title.

[This *Guardian* article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/nov/12/yunior-garcia-playwright-protest-cuba-government) from 2021 quotes ‘Hal Klepak, professor emeritus of history and strategy at the Royal Military College of Canada’ as saying:

> As San Ignacio de Loyola, echoing the same conclusion as Machiavelli in such circumstances, said: ‘In a besieged city, all dissent is treason.’

I can't find any evidence of Machiavelli saying that line, but it may be that Klepak was paraphrasing his argument. However, I also can't find any evidence of San Ignacio (Saint Ignatius in English) saying that quote.

An [online search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22In+a+besieged+city,+all+dissent+is+treason%22&filter=0&biw=1920&bih=920&dpr=1) for that exact quote returns: the *Guardian* article; a *Havana Times* article from 2013 that includes the quote in quotation marks but doesn't provide a source; and a bunch of content farms regurgitating the same *Guardian* article.

Searching for [the phrase in Spanish](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22en+una+ciudad+sitiada+toda+disidencia+es+traici%C3%B3n%22&filter=0&biw=1920&bih=920&dpr=1) also only yields a handful of results, which attribute it to Fidel Castro. [Tweaking the wording](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22En+una+fortaleza+sitiada%2C+toda+disidencia+es+traici%C3%B3n%22&biw=1920&bih=920&ei=ljSOZOLlKfe4qtsPvZey-As&ved=0ahUKEwjiiMGPrsv_AhV3nGoFHb2LDL8Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22En+una+fortaleza+sitiada%2C+toda+disidencia+es+traici%C3%B3n%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwIyBQghEKsCOgQIABBHOgUIABCiBEoECEEYAFByWJ0FYPsIaABwAngAgAGWA4gBqAiSAQUzLTIuMZgBAKABAaABAsABAcgBCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) (e.g., replacing ‘city’ with ‘fortress’) yields further hits attributing it to Castro, but usually saying he was quoting Ignacio (without providing a source).

[Searching for ‘Castro’](https://www.google.com/search?q=castro+%22dissent+is+treason%22&biw=1920&bih=920&ei=jDSOZLreBJuvqtsP4syaqAI&ved=0ahUKEwi61LmKrsv_AhWbl2oFHWKmBiUQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=castro+%22dissent+is+treason%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQogQyBQgAEKIEOgQIABBHSgQIQRgAUL0QWI0fYKkfaAFwAngAgAG_AogBwgaSAQUyLTIuMZgBAKABAcABAcgBCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) alongside part of the phrase (back to English again) returns many more results, including claims that the line was a 1960s Cuban propaganda motto.

So did San Ignacio ever say this (or anything similar), or did Castro/the Cuban government invent the phrase and it later (intentionally or unintentionally) got misattributed to San Ignacio?

Comment: I had the reverse doubt - how to translate that sentence into English. The original quote is actually "en una plaza sitiada toda disidencia es traición". I don't know if Loyola ever really wrote the sentence, but it is widely quoted as his in different Spanish-speaking countries. And yes, it was a propaganda slogan in Cuba, still used occasionally.